# Verilog task does not execute with delayed $finish in TB

Tags: verilog

I have the following code in my TB

```
 always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
 if(reset) reset_state;
 else begin 
    #1 run_task;
    if(<some check>) begin
      #2 $display ("something");
      #1000 $finish;
    end
 end
 end
```

So, every posedge if there is no reset I run a task, *run_task*. After running the task i do a simple check to see if task output is what I am expecting. If its not, I call $finish after a delay of 1000.

So simulation keeps on running (i have prints elsewhere to confirm it) for 1000 more timesteps before executing $finish and ending the sim. This is what I would expect.

But the doubt here is, in subsequent posedges after the *some check* failed, the simulation does not execute the task (confirmed with prints inside the task). The last time the task is executed is just before *some check* fails. I would expect it to run every time until the $finish is actually called.

Any idea if this is expected?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You description is incorrect; your `always` block does not execute every posedge.

What is does a start a process that executes a block of statements. And only after that block completes execution does it repeat the same block of statements.

The first statement in your block of statements `@(posedge clk)`c which means suspend the process waiting for a change event. In this case, `clk` going to 1 resumes the process. After that, if `reset` is false, the next statement #1 suspends the process for 1 time unit. Then it calls run_task. Any delays inside the task also suspends the process.

When some check fails, the process suspends for another 2 time units and then 1000 time units.  A clk event while the process is suspends does nothing because the process is not waiting for it to change. Its only after the block of statements completes does it go back an execute the statement that suspends the process waiting for another clk event.